# What is "as" in Controller's expression in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

The example in [Filter Angular Guide](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter) has Controller expression with "as", which I could not see documented there:

```
<div ng-controller="FilterController as ctrl">
```

What is the meaning of this syntax and why is it used instead of simply using the `$scope`?

---

EDIT. Thanks to very helpful links I understand that it can be good to access different Controllers from one Template. Is this correct? Does it mean I can access **any** controller like that?

As I am very new to Angular, I'm still puzzled whether it was really necessary in the linked Example.

Comment: http://www.thinkster.io/pick/GmI3KetKo6/angularjs-experimental-controller-as-syntax

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/84selECbp1I